# Cost Effective Ideas for Promoting a Poker Wiki?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I live in Las Vegas and I am tired of relying on message boards and directories to provide current information on Las Vegas poker rooms. So I have decided to create a non-commercial venture and create a poker wiki that anyone can update at any time with unique information on each cardroom. It is at http://pokerchurch.org

I am looking for cost effective ideas to promote a wiki like this. There are no advertisements, there is no commercial aspect to it; it's just a way for poker players to share information faster. Any ideas on how I can reach a broad user base for this?

Comment: If it's specific to Las Vegas, then local promotion is the way to go. Business cards, flyers and posters placed and given out around Las Vegas would build the best audience. A shorter URL would also be good, like `pcw.is` or something. I know I'm much more likely to check a site on my mobile if it's quick to get to. Finally, searching for and posting a link on existing similar initiatives such as Facebook pages, twitter groups and linked in groups could boost membership as well. Good luck!

Comment: How is this content going to be different from something like PokerAtlas?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer it's different because its a wiki, anyone can update it at any time, it's literally open to the public. Also, I'm encouraging users to post "esoteric" information. I don't want the phone numbers on there, I want info on new promotions, who the good staff are, quickest places to park for the room, etc, etc. It's not just a directory, it's intended more for "local knowledge" of the room. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may very well be wasting your time with this wiki project. I will tell what I found out about poker rooms, and poker players based on my experience doing something pretty much like what your attempting.

You said you were tired of relying on message boards and directories, this is a hint that there are problems keeping directories up to date. Some of these sites have staffs that do nothing but attempt to keep a directory up to date and they just can't do it very well.

The first problem is that no one on the casino floor is authorized to answer questions about the casino over the phone, except to answer customers simple questions. You can get contact information for all the casinos, Casino City web sit offers this service. As soon as poker room employee gets a whiff that you are trying to get information to publish online, they are going to refer you to marketing. Marketing is going to tell you that they do not have anything to do with poker tournaments and stuff. You get in to this circular pass the buck corporate BS. I would go to a card room in Las Vegas where I knew the card room manager well on a personal level and they would say plainly to me I cant give you anything like that, It has to go through marketing or some other office. They would hand me the tournament schedule and suggest I came in every couple of weeks and see if it changed.

I tried automation were I would give them a place were they could come online to update tournament schedules and the like, they could not get authorization to do this, and marketing did not understand enough about poker to do this.

I had a little suite of websites that was getting 300K unique visitors a month. Users will not take care of tournament schedules. They will write about there good time or bad time at a place, a short review, maybe give a rating of a poker room, but you cannot depend on them for good solid data for tournament schedules.

What I found was that it is a big deal for a casino to give anybody any kind of information for publishing. You would think you could walk in or call a place and say hey give me some information about your poker room and I will put it online. And they would say cool free advertising, but this is just simply not the case. They are in essence control freaks about their message to the public and do not give up that control.

The only entity that has come close to giving good solid information on a poker room is "Bravo", the people that make the player tracking you see in most poker rooms these days. They have an app that you can use to see what games are available at the poker rooms were the Bravo system is installed.

Bravo also allows the users of the system to have tournament schedules and other marketing information exposed in the app. However unlike the cash game information which is totally automated, information about tournaments and such is just plain text. There is no central form that makes building and updating a schedule an easy task. So there is a lot of degradation of the tournament schedule data.

I cant give you any cost effective ideals for promoting the wiki. To keep up to date information on any more then a few poker rooms is a daunting task. Poker managers for the most part do not mess with updating online stuff, and poker players cannot be relied on to keep it up to date. Other sources like poker rags and poker websites are not very accurate or up to date. Even if a poker room has its own website the tournament schedule is likely to be out of date.